# Trigonometric Ratios with half angles

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

If $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{y}{2}\right) = \tan^3\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{x}{2}\right)$, prove that $\sin(y) = \sin(x)\left[\frac{3+\sin^2(x)}{1 + 3\sin^2(x)}\right]$

I come until the step where

$ \cos{y}=\cos^3{x}$

After this I dont now what to do

Comment: [This looks curious](http://www2.clarku.edu/~djoyce/trig/triple.jpg).

Comment: Because $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$, you would have that $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + x\right) = \frac{\cos(x) + \sin(x)}{\cos(x) - \sin(x)}$.